# PostgreSQL aggregation with missing dates

Tags: sql, postgresql, select, aggregate-functions

I'm trying this query

```
SELECT date_trunc('day', commit_at) AS day, count(*)
  FROM commits
  GROUP BY date_trunc('day', commit_at)
  ORDER BY date_trunc('day', commit_at) ASC;
```

and it return

```
      day         | count 
---------------------+-------
2015-05-18 00:00:00 |     5
2015-05-19 00:00:00 |     2
2015-05-21 00:00:00 |     2
(3 lignes)
```

The question is: How I can force empty days to be in the results ?

```
      day         | count 
---------------------+-------
2015-05-18 00:00:00 |     5
2015-05-19 00:00:00 |     2
2015-05-20 00:00:00 |     0
2015-05-21 00:00:00 |     2
(3 lignes)
```

Comment: SQL can't create data from nothing.  You either have to have a system with dates, or use a method to create these dates to join or union in.  for example a recursive CTE that returns all dates between a date range.  Join back to this set so you get all dates regardless.  Here's one way: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13100445/adding-missing-date-in-a-table-in-postgresql  take a look at how @a_horse_with_no_name provided an answer or erwin's...

Comment: ok so the idea is to `generate_series` between first and last date then query theses dates ? I tried that but I can't have something working, if someone have an example

Comment: See link in first comment, examples are provided  and yes, Erwin uses `generate_series`

Answer (score 5):

One way of doing this is using nu [`generate_series`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/functions-srf.html) to generate all the days in between the minimal and maximal date, and then join it to the aggregate query:

```
SELECT    DATE_TRUNC ('day', 
                      GENERATE_SERIES (MIN(commit_at), MAX(commit_at), '1 day') 
             AS day, 
          COALESCE (cnt, 0)
FROM      commits
LEFT JOIN (SELECT   DATE_TRUNC('day', commit_at) AS cday
           FROM     commits
           GROUP BY DATE_TRUNC('day', commit_at)) agg ON day = cday
ORDER BY  1 ASC
```